# Cannot Log in into Windows 7 after installation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

My Toshiba laptop had windows 7 installed and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 into it. During installation I selected the last option 'Something else' not the 'Erase everything' option. During partition allocation, I created new partition list. In the time of creation I saw the windows 7 partition there, but after completion of Ubuntu installation, whenever I switch on the laptop it directly going to Ubuntu. Please help me to know that currently my system has windows 7 present in it or not? If there is windows, then how can get access to windows 7?
i tried boot-repair by using boot-repair disk,then also i cannot get access to windows 7

@riashat.rafat
below are the results when entered      df  -h     in my Ubuntu terminal

```
mohammedfarisk@MFK:~$ df -h
Filesystem          Size        Used      Avail     Use%     Mounted on
udev                914M         0         914M      0%       /dev
tmpfs               187M       5.4M        181M      3%       /run
/dev/sda1           28G        3.8G        23G      15%       /
tmpfs               931M       156K       931M      1%        /dev/shm
tmpfs               5.0M       4.0K       5.0M      1%        /run/lock
tmpfs               931M        0         931M      0%     /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5           9.1G      849M        7.8G     10%        /var
/dev/sda6           19G       185M        18G      2%        /home
cgmfs              100K        0         100K       0%  /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs              187M      4.0K        187M      1%      /run/user/119
tmpfs              187M      48K         187M      1%     /run/user/1000
mohammedfarisk@MFK:~$
```

please help me

Comment: Can you please open terminal and run `df -h` without quotation and show me the result?

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Comment: below are the results when entered      df  -h     in my Ubuntu terminal

Comment: @ David Foerster<br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must have been going wrong - there is no Windows system installed anymore.
As you can see in your [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14163890/) output there is only Ubuntu installed on partition sda1.
Unfortunately you will have to reinstall Windows 7 in case you want to have it back.
If you want to do so, it is recommended to first install Windows and then Ubuntu.
If you install Windows after Ubuntu, then you will have to reinstall GRUB later.
Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news ...

Comment: cl-netbox is right. If you lost data on the process you can read this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/  i suggest you to always back up your data when installing an OS just in case..

Comment: if i again install windows can i get all data's that were in my last windows 7 OS ?

Comment: @MohammedFaris.Kmuthumon : Dear friend, unfortunately not, everything you stored in Windows is gone, except what you stored in Ubuntu - you will have to rebuild everything in Windows from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

### **How to boot with a different OS**

When your computer starts if you have two or more operating systems you should see a screen like this (if you don't hold press **shif** or **esc** keys at the very start of your computer)

[image]

```
You should be able to read Windows 7
```

**I suggest you to take note of the line number windows 7 is**

---

### **Change default OS and/or boot menu delay**

If you were able to use Windows now you probably want to start your computer and be able see this screen again. To do that:

1. log in ubuntu
2. Open a terminal, by pressing ctrl + alt + t
3. Write this: `sudo apt-get install gksu` it will ask for your password write it and hit enter. **You will not see nothing as you type your password don't worry is normal**
4. Once **gksu** is installed type this:

> `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

[image]

**To change the time of boot menu**

Change the value of GRUB_TIMEOUT in the file to a number, (5 means 5 seconds). If you set the timeout to something extremely low – say, 1 second – you can access the boot menu by continually pressing the arrow keys or Escape key while your computer boots.

**To change defaul OS of boot menu**

If you want windows as your default OS when your computer starts change the value of GRUB_DEFAULT=0 in the file to the line number windows is. **This is why i suggested to write down the line number**

Save the file, and then run the following command on the terminal to apply your changes:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Now when you restart your computer it should show the boot screen menu and it should start the OS you've chosen

Comment: <\br>nothing happend newly sir<br/>in the time of booting i couldnt find a"windows" but i could see a window when i long pressed shift key same as that is in your first picture<br/>

Comment: I would recommend you to boot with the live usb or dvd that you used to install ubuntu and not install Ubuntu, but try ubuntu without installing, once there you can install grub repair and use it, that may solve your problem

Comment: here is a tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: after boot-repair i got a link http://paste.ubuntu.com/14163890/